# what's wrong with this C# code

Tags: c#, information-retrieval, inverted-index

I try to create an inverted index but it doesn't work. my codes have no error but doesn't work. what's wrong with it?

I get this exception every time : `KeyNotFoundException was unhandled : the given Key was not present in the dictionary`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
     class Program
     {
        static Dictionary<TItem, IEnumerable<TKey>> Invert<TKey, TItem>(Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TItem>> dictionary)
        {
            return dictionary
              .SelectMany(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Select(item => new KeyValuePair<TItem, TKey>(item, keyValuePair.Key)))
            .GroupBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key)
            .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value));
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("files: ");
            //read all the text document on the specified directory; change this directory based on your machine
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("D:\\IR\\", "*.txt"))
            {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(file);
            Console.WriteLine(contents);
            Console.Write("find: ");
            var find = Console.ReadLine();
            var dictionary = file.Split().ToDictionary(files => files, files => File.ReadAllText(file).Split().AsEnumerable());
            Console.WriteLine("{0} found in: {1}", find, string.Join(" ", Invert(dictionary)[find]));
            }
         }
     }
}
```

I edited the codes and now it work without error and exception. now there is another problem it must be able to read all of files only once but it can't I mean it every time read one of them and then do Finding process and it's not my point I need an output like what I wrote bellow. It seems I should change`foreach(string file in Dictionary.EnumerateFiles("D:\\IR\\","*.txt"))` to something else. but I don't know what it is.

output should be like this :

files: file1 file2 file3

find: what

what found in: file1 file2

Comment: How does it not work? What does it do wrong?

Comment: More often than not, you can fix bugs like these simply by stepping through your code and performing sanity checks to make sure that your variables have values you would expect them to have. Just my two cents.

Comment: it just unable to read the last line, can you tell me why?

Comment: @Tejas I guess it might be something wrong in " Program.Invert(dictionary)[find] ", isn't it?

Comment: Well your version of `Invert` appears to work just fine.

Comment: It appears the problem is here: Program.Invert(dictionary)[find] - try using .TryGetValue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx

Comment: @ChrisMoschini, I fixed exception but now there is another problem the output isn't exactly on my point, what's wrong? how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: I tested your version of `Invert` and that seems to work just fine. Are you getting confused by the default `ToString()` output? If you directly try to print `Program.Invert(dictionary)[find]`, you will not get the output you expect since the default `ToString()` is not very helpful (due to the fact that the object you are trying to print does not override `object.ToString()`). You will have to iterate through your list of values and individually print each one. Assuming `TKey` overrides `ToString()`, you will get the output you want. For example,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} found in: ", find);
foreach (var val in Program.Invert(dictionary)[find])
{
    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

**Previous Answer (saved for posterity):**
Alright, you mentioned that something is wrong in your `Invert` method. I tried to write up an `Invert` method of my own and here's what I came up with. I've broken up the method calls in to separate parts so that it's clear what I'm doing.

```
static Dictionary<TItem, IEnumerable<TKey>> Invert<TKey, TItem>(Dictionary<TKey, IEnumerable<TItem>> dictionary)
{
    // Get collection of all the values which will be keys in the new inverted dictionary
    var invertedDictKeys = dictionary.SelectMany(keyValPair => keyValPair.Value).Distinct();

    // Perform the invert
    var invertedDict = 
        invertedDictKeys.Select(
            invertedKey => 
            new KeyValuePair<TItem, IEnumerable<TKey>>(invertedKey, dictionary.Keys.Where(key => dict[key].Contains(invertedKey))));

    // Convert to dictionary and return
    return invertedDict.ToDictionary(keyValPair => keyValPair.Key, keyValPair => keyValPair.Value);
}
```

Comment: no, it doesn't work correctly and I still have the same bug " Key Not Found Exception was unhandled"even in separated version. when I changed " Directory.EnumerateFiles " to " Dictionary.GetFiles " it worked but the problem is it just work for first .txt file but I've five .txt files. another problem is even when I get output for my only first .txt file the bug is still there. I'm confused really don't know what to do

Comment: well you should have mentioned that was the exception getting thrown. Usually a good idea to provide as much info as possible in a SO question.

Comment: OK, now what do you think about it? is there any way?

Comment: I get this exception every time : 'Key not found exception was unhandled : the given key was not present in the dictionary'.

Comment: The exception means that whatever it is you are searching for does not actually exist in the inverted dictionary. Can you post some sample text from the text file you are reading in and also what you enter into your program?

Comment: Also, try breaking in your code and seeing what's actually "in" your dictionary. It could just be a matter of you forgetting to remove leading and trailing whitespaces from the text in your file or something like that.

Comment: I edited the question and it works now but the output isn't exactly on my point. can you tell me why? it seems something is wrong with " foreach " line. I've to change it but to what, I don't know.

Comment: Like I had mentioned in my answer, you won't get the output unless you enumerate all the members of your collection and print them individually.

Comment: can you help me, please, check this link out : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468094/try-to-answer-some-simple-boolean-queries-in-c-sharp)