# Try to answer some boolean queries using Term-Document-Incidence-Matrix

Tags: c#, winforms, information-retrieval

I try answer some simple boolean query in these ways `NOT x NOT y NOT z` also `x AND y AND z` and also like this `x OR y OR z` `x,y,z` are some words and any of them belongs to a different `file.txt`or maybe all of them belongs to same `file.txt`, no matter .

I've written a `class TermDocMatrix`:

it must be able to answer a boolean query , I prepared some methods in `class TermDocMatrix{ }`for these purposes but it doesn't work. I even debug the code step by step, I realized loops have no turn. I don't know why, codes seems fine.

well you can see code in here :

```
class TermDocMatrix
{
    //stores distinct terms
    public HashSet<string> distinctTerm = new HashSet<string>();
    //stores document id and its contents without splitting
    public Dictionary<int, string> documentContentList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    //stores document and its terms collection
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> documentCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> termDocumentIncidenceMatrix = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

     //stop words collection
    public List<string> stopWords = new List<string> { "on", "of", "The", "an", "a", "in" };
    //boolean operators list
    public string[] booleanOperator = new string[] { "AND", "OR", "NOT" };

    private string _FileName = "words";
    public string _Path = "";
    int _lastDocNum = 0;

    public TermDocMatrix(string IndexPath,string FileName)
    {

        if (_Path.EndsWith("\\") == false) _Path += "\\";
        if (!Directory.Exists(IndexPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(IndexPath);
        LogManager.Configure(_Path + _FileName + ".txt", false);
        // read all files
        LoadFiles();
    }

    private void LoadFiles()
    {
        int count = 0;

        if (File.Exists(_Path + _FileName + ".txt") == false)
            return;
        // load words
        string b = File.ReadAllText(_Path + _FileName + ".txt");
        String[] TermsCollection = RemoveStopsWords(b.ToUpper().Split(' '));
        foreach (string term in TermsCollection)
        {
            //prepeare distinct terms collection
            //remove stop words
            if (!stopWords.Contains(term))
            {
                distinctTerm.Add(term);
            }
        }
        //add document and their terms collection
        documentCollection.Add(_FileName, TermsCollection.ToList());
        //add document and its content for displaying the search result
        documentContentList.Add(count, b);
        count++;
    }
    public string ProcessFiles(string query)
    {
        termDocumentIncidenceMatrix = GetTermDocumentIncidenceMatrix(distinctTerm, documentCollection);
        do
        {
            List<int> lst = ProcessQuery(query);
            int count = 0;
            if (lst != null)
            {
                foreach (int a in lst)
                {
                    if (a == 1)
                    {
                         return documentContentList[count];
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "No search result found";
            }

        } while (1 == 1);
    }
    public int WordCount()
    {
        return documentCollection.Count;
    }

    public int DocumentCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _lastDocNum;
        }
    }

    private void FilterQueryTerm(ref string[] str)
    {
        List<string> _queryTerm = new List<string>();


        foreach (string queryTerm in str)
        {
            if (queryTerm.ToUpper().Equals("BUT") || termDocumentIncidenceMatrix.ContainsKey(queryTerm.ToUpper()) || booleanOperator.Contains(queryTerm))
            {
                _queryTerm.Add(queryTerm);

            }
        }

        str = _queryTerm.ToArray();
    }

    //prepares Term Document Incidence Matrix
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> GetTermDocumentIncidenceMatrix(HashSet<string> distinctTerms, Dictionary<string, List<string>> documentCollection)
    {
        Dictionary<string, List<int>> termDocumentIncidenceMatrix = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
        List<int> incidenceVector = new List<int>();
        foreach (string term in distinctTerms)
        {
            //incidence vector for each terms
            incidenceVector = new List<int>();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> p in documentCollection)
            {

                if (p.Value.Contains(term))
                {
                    //document contains the term
                    incidenceVector.Add(1);

                }
                else
                {
                    //document do not contains the term
                    incidenceVector.Add(0);
                }
            }
            termDocumentIncidenceMatrix.Add(term, incidenceVector);

        }
        return termDocumentIncidenceMatrix;
    }
    //removes all stop words
    public string[] RemoveStopsWords(string[] str)
    {
        List<string> terms = new List<string>();
        foreach (string term in str)
        {
            if (!stopWords.Contains(term))
            {
                terms.Add(term);
            }
        }
        return terms.ToArray();
    }
    //process the boolean query
    public List<int> ProcessQuery(string query)
    {

        //query boolean operator
        string bitWiseOp = string.Empty;
        string[] queryTerm = RemoveStopsWords(query.ToUpper().Split(' '));

        //remove query term that doesnot appears on document collection
        FilterQueryTerm(ref queryTerm);
        List<int> previousTermIncidenceV = null;
        List<int> nextTermsIncidenceV = null;
        //holds the bitwise operation result
        List<int> resultSet = null;
        //suppose on query X AND Y, X is previousTerm term and Y is nextTerm
        Boolean hasPreviousTerm = false;
        Boolean hasNotOperation = false;
        foreach (string term in queryTerm)
        {
            //is a term
            if (!booleanOperator.Contains(term) && !term.Equals("BUT"))
            {
                //query case: structure AND NOT analysis
                if (hasNotOperation)
                {

                    if (hasPreviousTerm)
                    {
                        nextTermsIncidenceV = ProcessBooleanOperator("NOT", GetTermIncidenceVector(term), nextTermsIncidenceV);
                    }
                    //query case: eg.NOT analysis
                    else
                    {
                        previousTermIncidenceV = ProcessBooleanOperator("NOT", GetTermIncidenceVector(term), nextTermsIncidenceV);
                        resultSet = previousTermIncidenceV;
                    }
                    hasNotOperation = false;
                }
                else if (!hasPreviousTerm)
                {
                    previousTermIncidenceV = GetTermIncidenceVector(term);
                    resultSet = previousTermIncidenceV;
                    hasPreviousTerm = true;
                }
                else
                {

                    nextTermsIncidenceV = GetTermIncidenceVector(term);
                }
            }
            else if (term.Equals("NOT"))
            {
                //indicates that the  term in the next iteration should be complemented.
                hasNotOperation = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //'BUT' also should be evaluated as AND eg. structure BUT NOT semantic should be evaluated as structure AND NOT semantic
                if (term.Equals("BUT"))
                {
                    bitWiseOp = "AND";
                }
                else
                    bitWiseOp = term;
            }

            if (nextTermsIncidenceV != null && !hasNotOperation)
            {
                resultSet = ProcessBooleanOperator(bitWiseOp, previousTermIncidenceV, nextTermsIncidenceV);
                previousTermIncidenceV = resultSet;
                hasPreviousTerm = true;
                nextTermsIncidenceV = null;
            }
        }

        return resultSet;
    }

    //Process Boolean operators
    public List<int> ProcessBooleanOperator(string op, List<int> previousTermV, List<int> nextTermV)
    {
        List<int> resultSet = new List<int>();
        if (op.Equals("NOT"))
        {
            foreach (int a in previousTermV)
            {
                if (a == 1)
                {
                    resultSet.Add(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultSet.Add(1);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (op.ToUpper().Equals("AND")) //bitwise AND operation
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < previousTermV.Count; a++)
            {
                if (previousTermV[a] == 1 && nextTermV[a] == 1)
                {
                    resultSet.Add(1);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultSet.Add(0);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (op.ToUpper().Equals("OR")) //bitwise OR operation
        {
            for (int a = 0; a < previousTermV.Count; a++)
            {
                if (previousTermV[a] == 0 && nextTermV[a] == 0)
                {
                    resultSet.Add(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    resultSet.Add(1);
                }
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

    //returns term incidence vector
    public List<int> GetTermIncidenceVector(string term)
    {
        return termDocumentIncidenceMatrix[term.ToUpper()];

    }
}
```

you need to now about another class named `Class LogManager` I used it on my `Class TermDocMatrix`.  Here :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
   internal class FileLogger
   {
    public static readonly FileLogger Instance = new FileLogger();

    private string _filename;
    private bool _showMethodName = false;
    private string _FilePath = "";

    public bool ShowMethodNames
    {
        get { return _showMethodName; }
    }

    public void Init(string filename, bool showmethodnames)
    {
        _showMethodName = showmethodnames;
        _filename = filename;
        // handle folder names as well -> create dir etc.
        _FilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
        if (_FilePath != "")
        {
            _FilePath = Directory.CreateDirectory(_FilePath).FullName;
            if (_FilePath.EndsWith("\\") == false)
                _FilePath += "\\";
        }
    }
}
internal static class LogManager
{

    public static void Configure(string filename, bool showmethodnames)
    {
        FileLogger.Instance.Init(filename, showmethodnames);
    }
}
```

}

it must work but it don't. tell me why don't it work, please. when I ask for answer I just see this "No search result found", no matter I'd typed what kind of boolean query.

Comment: You've shown us huge amounts of unrelated code, but you haven't shown us `ProcessQuery` - which is the only *important* piece. That's presumably returning `null`, but we'll have no idea why without seeing it. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list - you need to significantly cut down the code in the question, but make sure you include all the *relevant* code.

Comment: @JonSkeet processQuery works correctly in a console aplication,

Comment: Then you changed something when you copied it to your WinForms application.

Comment: @Olivia: I don't understand what you're hoping we can achieve. You've posted *lots* of irrelevant code, when all that's relevant is whether `ProcessQuery` returns `null` or not. You're now saying we don't need to see the code for `ProcessQuery` because you're sure it works. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: Something changed: it's now returning `null`. If you copied the method verbatim, then look for changes to its dependencies (e.g. variables outside the method itself). Perhaps something isn't getting initialised? Or is getting set to the wrong value? It's all guesswork on our part without seeing the method.

Comment: @Ginosaji, only thing I changed was static void Main(string x). I change it to public string ProcessFiles(string x)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for that link I read it. It was useful, How does my question look ,now???

Comment: @JonSkeet am I ask a right question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line: (`ProcessFiles` function)

```
String[] termsCollection = RemoveStopsWords(file.ToUpper().Split(' '));
```

you're splitting the **name** of the file and not its **content**
That's why you have no search results

you should do something like this instead:

```
String[] termsCollection = RemoveStopsWords(File.ReadAllText(file).ToUpper().Split(' '));
```

Now change your `TermDocMatrix` constructor:

```
public TermDocMatrix(string IndexPath,string FileName)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(IndexPath)) Directory.CreateDirectory(IndexPath);
    LogManager.Configure(System.IO.Path.Combine(_Path, _FileName + ".txt"), false);
    // read all files
    LoadFiles();
}
```

And your `LoadFiles` function:

```
private void LoadFiles()
{
    int count = 0;

    if (File.Exists(System.IO.Path.Combine(_Path, _FileName + ".txt")) == false)
        return;
    // load words
    string b = File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.Combine(_Path, _FileName + ".txt"));

    .....
}
```

Comment: everything is same to same it doesn't work unfortunately, I was confused,I really don't know what to do. any solvent, please.

Comment: I think that was one of the problems anyway. Have you tried the step by step debugging in your `ProcessQuery` function? What is the value of `query` when you call it?

Comment: I found out why my code doesn't work in winfrom, actually I made my ProcessFiles method according to my main method in Console application but the main is a static method and I ignore the static because if I turn back ProcessFiles method to static I've no access to it, it's my problem, I've to use ProcessFiles method in button6, so what should I do??? ProcessFiles doesn't work without static access.

Comment: I've no access to static methods of TermDocMatrix class to use in Form1.cs.

Comment: the value of query must be the boolean query typed by me in textbox.

Comment: well that value should be the one you typed, but what is it when you run your code? Also if you can't access your static methods, your code shouldn't even compile, so I think you mixed up something here

Comment: and you can access those static methods if they're public, just use `TermDocMatrix.YourStaticMethod`. You should review your UML model though to be sure what is accessible where

Comment: nooooooo, it doesn't work,too. it was the only thing keep me hopeful, now I'm a loser

Comment: I don't want give it up. I keep try, so please let me know if you have any idea, ok?

Comment: I can't tell you more based on the information I have, the code source isn't complete and I can't debug it, so try debugging it step by step and see which part of your code doesn't behave as you wish. Once you've identified it let me know (but I think you'll be able to fix it yourself at that moment)

Comment: I added more details, check it out please, thank you.

Comment: Ok, does the file you're trying to load exists? (second line of `LoadFiles` method) Does it go directly to `return`?

Comment: Ofcourse, it does. I checked the files but loops of class TermDocMatrix have no repeat,none of them, I found it when I did debug into steps, and now I think that's because ProcessFiles method every time return null value and the result will turn to "No Search Result Found", what should I do? any idea

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `return` line in your `LoadFiles` method and tell me if it gets hit. I'm sure your code just doesn't load the file that's why you have no results (I tested it).

Comment: How? I mean puting a breakpoint, how?

Comment: .... put the cursor on the line, click and then press `F9`

Comment: I did it, your right it got hit. now what should I do?

Comment: what will happen now? return line gets hit.

Comment: This means that your file doesn't exists in this path. Check the path and correct it, then it should work.

Comment: I edited my answer, and if you do what I say in it your code should work. But what you really should do is take programming lessons, your code is quite messy, and you clearly don't understand some basics about code writing (and debugging). If you're in France I can give some lessons ;) (but not for free)

Comment: thanks for your offer but I'm not in France. you're a good guy, you try help me remotely and I appreciate for that. by the way it didn't work,too. now I'm sure problem is my LogManager Class I added it to question, check it out, please. thanks

Comment: ,I edited the question, right now. please check it. thanks

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow, I have to go now sorry

Comment: mention not,please. it's OK

Comment: Check this link out please  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436037/how-to-prepare-method-for-button-in-winforms).   maybe you can help me, so please check link out,please.you always have a magic solution for me and I trust you. don't keep me waiting so long, OK?

Comment: Ok, what is the problem with your logmanager? Also people on SO can help you with some problems, but they won't debug all your code or write the code you need for you. Again, take some lessons or you'll get stuck at one moment or another

Comment: Thank to you I finally found the problem and I fixed it by my own last night, now tell me did you check this link out :  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436037/how-to-prepare-method-for-button-in-winforms it's another question I really stuck at it, I need some explain to fix two error but nobody help me. please check the link.

Comment: If you want people to help you on SO, read the FAQ, also be more clear about the error you get, vote for useful answers, and if an answer helps you solve your problem, mark it as resolved